# Cannot insert data to Database Java without any error

Tags: java, jdbc

I have tried to add stmt.executeUpdate(); to insert to the database, but it still not working!! After processing, no error is shown but no data is insert into the database.

```
            try {
                // do insert
                String preparedSQL = "insert into abc (NUM, ID) VALUES (?,?)";

                for(int i = 1; i < r.length; i++)
                {


                stmt = conn.prepareStatement(preparedSQL);
                // SQL parameters
                setString(stmt, i++, Num);
                setString(stmt, i++, r[i]);
                stmt.executeQuery();


                }
                stmt.executeUpdate();
                stmt.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {

                PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(res
                        .getOutputStream(), "Big5"), true);
                res.setContentType("text/html; charset=utf-8");
                res.setHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");
                res.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
                res.setIntHeader("expiry", -1000);
                out.println("..<!--" + RSCommonUtil.HTMLEncode(e.toString()) + "para in title not valid" + 
                RSCommonUtil.HTMLEncode(pDate.toString())
                        + " " + RSCommonUtil.HTMLEncode(startPubDateAndEndPubDate[0].toString()) + " "
                        + RSCommonUtil.HTMLEncode(startPubDateAndEndPubDate[1].toString()) + "-->");

                debug.p("insert error" + e);
                failed = true;
            } finally {
                try {
                    // finalize DB
                    if (stmt != null) {
                        stmt.close();
                        stmt = null;
                    }
                } catch (SQLException sqle) {
                }
            }
```

Comment: "Urgent help" removed from your question title: please remember that while the problem is urgent for you, it shouldn't be made urgent for us as your question/problem is not more important than any one else's on this site. To improve your chances of getting a quick and decent answer, rather than stating "urgent", strive to ask the best question possible as per the [ask] link.

Comment: You're using executeQuery(), not executeUpdate(). And you only need to prepare the statement once: that's the whole point of a prepared statement.

Comment: This, `catch (SQLException sqle) {
                }` may not be wise. At least print the stacktrace, as you may be missing a key exception.

Comment: And you print nothing to the console if you get an error. Only inside an HTML comment, to `out`. My guess is that you haven't read the HTML comment that this method produced. You really should not mix HTML generation with database access code.

Comment: Another possible issue: If your database connection isn't set for auto-commit then your insert is un-committed. Also, you're closing your `stmt` once at the end of the `try` body and a second time in the `finally` block.

Comment: Always search Stack Overflow thoroughly before posting. Inserting rows into a database via JDBC has been covered many times already. This fact may explain the down-votes on this Question.

Comment: When posting to Stack Overflow, always strip down your code to an absolute minimum. For example here, the generation of HTML for error-reporting is nothing but a distraction that wastes the valuable time of your readers. Also, in producing a stripped-down working example, you are quite likely to solve your own problem.

Answer (score 2):

`executeUpdate` is for create, drop, insert, update, delete etc., (i.e., updating your table), `executeQuery` is for select. It returns an instance of ResultSet.

See here for simple explanation: https://www.javatpoint.com/PreparedStatement-interface

Also, your `setString` has an incorrect number of parameters and it should be called as a method of the statement object, and the parameterIndex (first parameter of the `setString` method) should just be `i`, as you will otherwise increment three times for each iteration. I also changed the loop to start at 0, don't know why you would start at 1 as a normal array should start at 0.

So your main block would be something like this:

```
...
            // do insert
            String preparedSQL = "insert into abc (NUM, ID) VALUES (?,?)";

            PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(preparedSQL);

            for(int i = 0; i < r.length; i++)
            {

            // SQL parameters
            stmt.setString(i, Num);
            stmt.setString(i, r[i]);
            stmt.executeUpdate();


            }
            stmt.close();
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Inside the try block, try rewriting the code as follows:

```
String preparedSQL = "insert into abc (NUM, ID) VALUES (?,?)";
for(int i = 1; i < r.length; i++)
{
    stmt = conn.prepareStatement(preparedSQL);
    // SQL parameters
    stmt.setString(1, Num);
    stmt.setString(2, r[i]);
    stmt.executeUpdate();
    stmt.close();
}
```

The setString method takes only two parameters.

> public void setString(int paramIndex, String value)

Here 'paramIndex' refers to the index of the parameter in your prepared statement and 'value' refers to which value you want to insert at that index.

The executeQuery() method of prepared statement interface is used for SELECT queries. But in your case, since the statement is an INSERT query, you will have to use executeUpdate() method. This method is used for CREATE, DROP, UPDATE, INSERT, etc. statements.

Refer [this](https://www.javatpoint.com/PreparedStatement-interface) for more information regarding prepared statements and sample code.

Answer (score 0):

The other Answers [by yalda](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57340652/642706) and [by Nitish](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57340678/642706) are both correct, with good advice. Ditto for some comments on the Question. I can add one more thought, plus a full working example app that writes and reads rows using the [H2 Database Engine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H2_(DBMS)).

## Try-With-Resources

Use the [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) syntax to shorten your code, and guarantee your resources get closed appropriately.

## Example app

```
package work.basil.example;


import org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource;

import java.sql.*;
import java.time.OffsetDateTime;
import java.time.ZoneOffset;
import java.util.UUID;

public class H2DateTimeExample
{
    public static void main ( String[] args )
    {
        H2DateTimeExample app = new H2DateTimeExample ();
        app.demo ();
    }

    private void demo ( )
    {
        JdbcDataSource dataSource = new JdbcDataSource ();
        dataSource.setURL ( "jdbc:h2:mem:offsetdatetime_example_db;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1" ); // Set `DB_CLOSE_DELAY` to `-1` to keep in-memory database in existence after connection closes.
        dataSource.setUser ( "scott" );
        dataSource.setPassword ( "tiger" );

        // Create table.
        String sql = "CREATE TABLE person_ ( \n" +
                " pkey_ UUID NOT NULL DEFAULT RANDOM_UUID() PRIMARY KEY , \n" +
                " name_ VARCHAR NOT NULL , \n" +
                "first_contacted_ TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE NOT NULL " +
                ") ;";
//            System.out.println ( sql );
        try (
                Connection conn = dataSource.getConnection () ;
                Statement stmt = conn.createStatement () ;
        )
        {
            stmt.execute ( sql );
        } catch ( SQLException e )
        {
            e.printStackTrace ();
        }

        // Insert row.
        sql = "INSERT INTO person_ ( name_ , first_contacted_ ) \n";
        sql += "VALUES ( ? , ? ) \n";
        sql += ";";
        try (
                Connection conn = dataSource.getConnection () ;
                PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement ( sql , Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS ) ;
        )
        {
            OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.now ( ZoneOffset.UTC );

            pstmt.setString ( 1 , "Jesse Johnson" );
            pstmt.setObject ( 2 , odt );
            pstmt.executeUpdate ();

            ResultSet rs = pstmt.getGeneratedKeys ();
//            System.out.println( "INFO - Reporting generated keys." );
//            while ( rs.next() ) {
//                UUID uuid = rs.getObject( 1 , UUID.class );
//                System.out.println( "generated keys: " + uuid );
//            }

        } catch ( SQLException e )
        {
            e.printStackTrace ();
        }


        // Query table.
        sql = "TABLE person_ ;";
        try (
                Connection conn = dataSource.getConnection () ;
                PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement ( sql ) ;
        )
        {
            try ( ResultSet rs = pstmt.executeQuery () ; )
            {
                while ( rs.next () )
                {
                    UUID pkey = rs.getObject ( "pkey_" , UUID.class );
                    String name = rs.getString ( "name_" );
                    OffsetDateTime firstContacted = rs.getObject ( "first_contacted_" , OffsetDateTime.class );
                    System.out.println ( "pkey: " + pkey + " | name: " + name + " | firstContacted: " + firstContacted );
                }
            }

        } catch ( SQLException e )
        {
            e.printStackTrace ();
        }

        System.out.println ( "Done." );

    }
}
```

> pkey: 0819123b-5c7f-4859-bd1b-f9dac82b855f | name: Jesse Johnson | firstContacted: 2019-08-03T18:16:30.367840Z
>
> Done.